# Win-PS2EXE - Respect the location of the resulting executable

Tags: powershell

Take these settings for the program **[Win-PS2EXE](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PS2EXE-GUI-Convert-e7cb69d5)**:

This is so that the console will show when the `exe` file is clicked on.

[image: Win-PS2EXE]

And this code:

```
$inf_file = "$PSScriptRoot\setup-files\install.inf"
write-host """$inf_file"""
timeout 10
```

Let us say that the path of the new executable is `W:\Apps\Install Scheme.exe`

Which means the `$inf_file` is here `W:\Apps\setup-files\install.inf`

---

When I click the converted exe file I get this.

[image]

Is there any way to get the correct path of `W:\Apps\setup-files\install.inf` so that the executable recognises the location of itself when clicked.

I thought that `$PSScriptRoot` would work.

I'm lost as to how to get around this as the exe file will eventually depend on knowing its location.

Comment: Q: So you want the new .exe to "remember" at runtime?  The value of $PSScriptRoot" when you ran PS2EXE/Win-PS2EXE?  Q: Is there any reason you couldn't just use `Get-Location` in your PS script?

Comment: Exactly. It was the `ps1` path variable that I wanted the `exe` to also use so it would behave in the same manner. I found the answer on the homepage. Check the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the code that can accomplish that.

```
Function Get-PSScriptPath {

<#

.SYNOPSIS
Returns the current filepath of the .ps1 or compiled .exe with Win-PS2EXE.

.DESCRIPTION
This will return the path of the file. This will work when the .ps1 file is
converted with Win-PS2EXE

.NOTES
Author: Ste
Date Created: 2021.05.03
Tested with PowerShell 5.1 and 7.1.
Posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60121313/8262102

.PARAMETER None
NA

.INPUTS
None. You cannot pipe objects to Get-PSScriptPath.

.OUTPUTS
Returns the current filepath of the .ps1 or compiled .exe with Win-PS2EXE.

.EXAMPLE (When run from a .ps1 file)
PS> Get-PSScriptPath
PS> C:\Users\Desktop\temp.ps1

.EXAMPLE (When run from a compiled .exe file with Win-PS2EXE.
PS> Get-PSScriptPath
PS> C:\Users\Desktop\temp.exe

#>

if ([System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($PSCommandPath) -eq '.ps1') {
  $psScriptPath = $PSCommandPath
  } else {
    # This enables the script to be compiles and get the directory of it.
    $psScriptPath = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName
  }
  return $psScriptPath
}

Get-PSScriptPath
```

Answer (score 4):

To offer a pragmatic, concise alternative (PSv3+) that always reports the script path as a *full* path:

One-liner:

```
$scriptDir = if (-not $PSScriptRoot) { Split-Path -Parent (Convert-Path ([environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()[0])) } else { $PSScriptRoot }
```

Annotated form:

```
$scriptDir = if (-not $PSScriptRoot) {  # $PSScriptRoot not defined?
    # Get the path of the executable *as invoked*, via
    # [environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()[0],
    # resolve it to a full path with Convert-Path, then get its directory path
    Split-Path -Parent (Convert-Path ([environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()[0])) 
  } 
  else {
    # Use the automatic variable.
    $PSScriptRoot 
  }
```